# How to erase/delete/wipe the migration history in Django

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I'm experimenting with varios django modells and settings.

I can't erase the migration history which is make me upset.

I have run this script and physically delete all .pyc files and the database.

```
del /s /q *.pyc
del /q db.sqlite3
```

After I typed:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and I got this:

```
No changes detected
```

I tired this as well:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

no luck.

Obviously I have tried to delete all files under migrations folder even I deleted that folders as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

> del /q db.sqlite3

you've deleted your database (and all of the applied migrations there), which is all dandy, but the migrations themselves remain as Python files on disk (in `<app>/migrations/*.py`).

The

> No changes detected

you get when you run `makemigrations` means there are no new migration files that would need to be created.

If you really want to get rid of all migrations, i.e. all of the history of your how models have evolved, you will also need to delete the migration script files under your apps' `migrations/` folders.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. Somehow Django stored my info what not really nice.

Comment: @StJoesy What "doesn't work"? There are two places where migrations are stored: migration files, and your database.

Comment: 1. I deleted all *.pyc on my project folder and my minicona folder.
2. deletede anything. under migrations
3. Restarted my machine.
Than same message: "No changes detected" whlist djnago must be consider this is a brand new project. 
4. I even  renamed my project.

Comment: If you've deleted all `migrations/*.py` files everywhere in your project, and your database as well, there **can be nowhere else** Django might be "hiding" your information.

Comment: @StJoesy Of course if there are e.g. no models, or nothing in INSTALLED_APPS, then Django won't find anything that would need migrations generated.

Comment: I have accepted your answer because basically you were right and it was the first answer and you also tried "hard" to understand the problem. The "root" of my problem was the Django file structure or app settings error. I have recreated the project and i could not repeat the mistake.

Comment: Glad I could help. Maybe look into version control with e.g. Git for your next project so you can backtrack to a known good version when something like this happens? :)